# Nodejs : Why does db.collection().find() log multiple times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, request

so when i execute my query to find an object by id, it finds it but logs it like 5 times! i know its not mch code to really get into the issue but thanks for the help :)

```
      static findUserById(id) {
            const db = getDb();
            return db
            .collection('users')
            .findOne({ _id: new mongodb.ObjectId(id)})
            .then(user => {
                console.log(user);
                return user;
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure this method is not getting called 5 times? instead of findOne?

Comment: yea im sure, i only call it once : app.use((request,response,next) => {
    User.findUserById("5d07c01f1c9d4400002047b5") ;  next(); }

Comment: This will run on every request to your server, rather than a specific route. Does your app make multiple requests to the server?

Comment: yeah it does, i guess thats why, thanks for the input :)